# Python check if a value in a list exists in another list

Tags: python

I have a requirement, where I am trying to find if a value in a list is found in another list and then just take that value alone.

For Example

```
MyCountryList = ( 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Russia')

data = (['United States', 'IDB', 1989, Decimal('275200141')],
 ['United States', 'IDC', 1990, Decimal('282899816')],
'India', 'IDD', 1989, Decimal('275200141')],
 ['India', 'IDE', 1990, Decimal('282899816')])
```

I want my output to have the United States only as this is the only country present in both the lists on this format without the word decimal and '' on the list.

```
MyRequiredList = (['United States', 'IDB', '1989', '275200141'],
 ['United States', 'IDC', '1990', '282899816'])


data[0] gives me this ['United States', 'IDB', 1989, Decimal('92490932')]
```

Comment: So you want the intersection of 2 lists?

Comment: @yes and I don't want the word decimal in it and would want the years to have ' ' on it to insert into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
MyCountryList = ( 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Russia')

data = (['United States', 'IDB', 1989, Decimal('275200141')],
  ['United States', 'IDC', 1990, Decimal('282899816')],
    ['India', 'IDD', 1989, Decimal('275200141')],
   ['India', 'IDE', 1990, Decimal('282899816')])
final_data = [i for i in data if i[0] in MyCountryList]
```

Output:

```
[['United States', 'IDB', 1989, Decimal('275200141')], ['United States', 'IDC', 1990, Decimal('282899816')]]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I think there could be a problem with the data list that I am getting through a request.

Comment: @Sid29 what specifically is the error message or incorrect output?

Comment: It appears empty. Can you infer something from the last line that I have updated on the question. data[0] gives me such an Information...

Comment: @Sid29 odd, it should work, since that is the first line `data` in my answer above.